# Plone custom viewlets.xml not being picked up

Tags: plone, genericsetup, viewlets

Quoting http://plone.org/documentation/kb/customizing-main-template-viewlets/tutorial-all-pages (about 1/4 of the page down)

> If all you need is to reorder the viewlets in the Plone Default skin, you can simply copy the original viewlets.xml from CMFPlone/profiles/default/ into MyTheme/profiles/default/, and edit the copied file to make it reflect your needs.

When I do just that, I get no changes, not after reloading, not after a buildout, not anyhow. I did some slight manual changes to MyTheme/browser/templates/main_template.pt, which are picked up, so it is not so, that my product is ignored at all. So far I did not touch any essential code there, so this cannot be the reason.

This is for a plone 3.3.5 install. Anybody could give me clue here? Any infos needed, I am standing by :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GenericSetup profiles need to be explicitly loaded, they are not loaded on start-up.

You can do this by either reinstalling your package in the QuickInstaller. Alternatively, you can just re-import just viewlets.xml via the setup tool. You'll find that tool in the ZMI (look for the `portal_setup` tool):

[image: portal_setup]

Once there you select the `Import` tab:

[image: Import tab on the portal_setup tool]

You'll then have to find your package profile in the drop-down list:

[image: Select Profile or Snapshot]

The tab will automatically reload once you make your choice. Scroll down to the "Viewlet Settings" step and check it's checkbox:

[image: Viewlet settings step]

Then finally, uncheck the "Include dependencies?" checkbox at the bottom and click the "Import selected steps" button:

[image: Import selected steps button]

Comment: @aclark: That's just because Firefox makes the ZMI look good! ;-)

Comment: What difference does unchecking "Include dependencies" make?

Comment: @artemis_clyde: setup steps have *dependencies*, steps that need to run before them in order for them to work when setting up from scratch. Re-importing just the viewlets doesn't require other setup steps to run first, unchecking that box makes sure you don't accidentally break stuff that you have since changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall the product from portal_quickinstaller

Answer (score 0):

Every xml files under profiles/XXX are meant to be configuration 'profile' It means it is not a configuration file but a profile. So you need to apply the profile.

Buildout has to be run when you have changes like add/remove/update eggs or eggs dependencies (setup.py).

Restarting zope is needed when you have made changes to python files outside of skins directories or you have made changes to zcml files. Note changes on templates, css, js do not need restart except if you are in production mode.

How to apply a profile:

Default profile can be applyed throw the add-on activation panel (aka Quick Installer)

If you just want to apply one step (this is your case) you can go to ZMI in portal_setup, Select import tabs and select the *viewlets* step and submit the form.

Comment: You'll need to select the correct profile on the import tab before submitting the form. Also, just submitting the form could mean 'run all steps'. Last but not least, if you use the 'import selected step' button but forget to uncheck the 'include dependencies' box next to it, you are all but running all import steps anyway. :-)